# Bash parallelization for double for loop

Tags: bash, performance, for-loop, parallel-processing, wait

So I have a function that request REST API and that takes in two arguments: instances and dates. I am given a list of instances and a range of dates which need to be iterated with two for loops. One constraint is that the only one instance can be requested at a time.

I have tried using `&` and `wait`, and my pseudocode looks like this.

```
for each date:
    for each instance:
        do-something "$date" "$instance" &
    done
    wait
done
```

This actually works perfectly since only one instance is requested at a time and only progress when all instances are processed and therefore no instance gets requested at the same time.

The problem is that some request for certain instance takes a long time, so other instances that have been processed earlier are idling. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you only allowed to have requests out to a single value of `$instance` at a time? If so how does your problem work? If a date request to a given instance it taking a long time how can you move on past it? Doing that would mean you now have requests pending to more than one instance at a time, no? Or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function which will process a given instance for each date sequentially:

```
for_each_date () {
    instance=$1
    shift
    for d in "$@"; do
        some_command "$d" "$instance"
    done
}
```

Now, spawn a background process to run this function for each instance.

```
dates=(2015-07-21 2015-07-22 2015-07-23)  # For example
instances=(inst1 inst2 inst3)

for instance in "${instances[@]}"; do
    for_each_date "$instance" "${dates[@]}" &
done
wait
```

Each background job will run `some-command` for a different instance, and will never run more than one process at a time, so you meet your first constraint. At the same time, `for_each_date` starts a new request for its instance as soon as the old one completes, keeping your machine as busy as possible.

Comment: So I have been implementing this lately, and I was just wondering why we need shift under `for_each_date` function? I know it's shifting $n to $n+1, but what practical purpose does it serve?

Comment: `$@` includes both the instance and all the dates; using `shift` removes the instance so that we can iterate over just the dates using `$@`; without the shift, you would have to either iterate over `${@:2}` or somehow otherwise skip the first element of `$@` in the body of the for loop.

Comment: Oh that makes a ton of sense. If we are feeding in only one argument (instances) to for_each_date, we wouldn't need shift, correct?

Comment: That depends. If you mean that `for_each_date` only *expects* one argument (and doesn't try to iterate over `$@`), then you don't need shift. But if `for_each_date` expects an instance and 0 or more dates, then it still needs the shift to reduce `$@` from one item to zero.

Comment: Yes, it's the former. The dates are calculated outside of the functions and fed in as a global variable. Also, do you know how to change this into xargs command line? I know & forks a process, but it only uses one core, right? I want to use xargs so that the script utilizes all $(nproc) cores on the machine.

Comment: When you create a background process, the OS should use any core that's available. The benefit of using `xargs` is that you can *limit* the number of cores that are used for background processes.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you would do:

```
parallel do-something ::: d a t e s ::: i n s t a n c e s
```